# WHILE and IF combination in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I am a newbie in Python so I am trying to do some basic code.
Below you can see a simple code, but it gives me subsequent error:
**File "", line 9
print('Not your number.')
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block**

```
c = 0

while c < 5:
    
    print(f'The current number is: {c}')
    c = c + 1
    
    if c == 4:
    print('Not your number.')

else:
    print ('You have reached your limit.')
```

Could you please help me in finding the mistake? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you looked into the indentation requirements for an ‘if’ statement yet?

Comment: Check out the official Python tutorial about control flow https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html. Does your `if` statement look like those in the tutorial? How is it different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation in python matters. When you have a statement which expects a block of code to execute after it like an if statement or a while loop if you don't provide a properly indented block you will get a syntax error.

```
c = 0

while c < 5:
    
    print(f'The current number is: {c}')
    c = c + 1
    
    if c == 4:
        print('Not your number.') # this statement has to be indented because of the if statement
else:
    print ('You have reached your limit.')
```

Comment: Why should the indentation be like this?

Comment: @quamrana I corrected it, thank you!

Comment: I’m not saying anything is correct or incorrect. You don’t give a reason why it should be one way or another.

Comment: @quamrana yes, I updated my answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Just as you indent in your bottom else clause, you must indent for your if clause in your while loop. The below should work.

```
c = 0

while c < 5:
    
    print(f'The current number is: {c}')
    c = c + 1
    
    if c == 4:
        print('Not your number.')

else:
    print ('You have reached your limit.')
```